# Carbon 13 NMR peaks - ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

Why the shift of acetophenone's carbonyl carbon at C13 NMR spectrum is larger than the equivalent peak at trifluoroacetophenone ? Particularly , the first one is located at 197.94 ppm whereas the second at 179.59 ppm . Normally the presence of an EWG deshields the carbon more easily , right ?
It would be helpful if anyone could answer this .
Thank you very much !